# Updating a variable during asynchronous function time out

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
const counter = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    // setValue(value + 1);
    setValue((prevState) => prevState + 1);
  }, 2000);
};
```

`counter` is called when a button is pressed i.e.

```
<button onClick={counter}>counter</button>
```

Why does `setValue(value + 1)` update the value once  if I press the button multiple times, but `setValue((prevState) => prevState + 1)` return the correct value relative to the amount pressed?

Comment: if you try <button onClick={() => setValue(value + 1)}>counter</button> it should work as expected. Have a look here for more info https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#updating-state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State updates are not always immediate. Using the previous value ensures that you are working with the current value at the point in time where the value is being set. Kent Dodds explains this well [in this post](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/use-state-lazy-initialization-and-function-updates). Bigger question might be, why are you wrapping this in a `setTimeout`?

Comment: Thank you. I saw this snippet in a tutorial the `setTimeOut` was only for a demonstration purpose.